# Reading XML same tag name values to a list of class

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read an `XML` tags using `C#` to a class. This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <setting>
        <autosave onoff="false" minute="10"/>
        <catpriority category="false"/>
        <autobackup onoff="false" backuppath="c:\"/>
    </setting>
    <database>
        <db dbid="0" conn="" writer="" active="true" />
        <db dbid="1" conn="" writer="" active="false" />
        <db dbid="2" conn="" writer="" active="false" />
    </database>
</configuration>
```

I create two classes to save `XML` values.

```
public class Configuration
    {
        public bool SaveOnoff { get; set; }
        public string Minute { get; set; }
        public bool Category { get; set; }
        public bool BackupOnoff { get; set; }
        public string Backuppath { get; set; }
        public List<Db> DbList =new List<Db>();
    }

    public class Db
    {
        public int Dbid { get; set; }
        public string Conn { get; set; }
        public string Writer { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

I read the `XML` values using this code:

```
private Configuration Config = new Configuration();
var res =Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Configuration))
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("mynamespace.Resources.Configuration.xml");

var xReader = new XmlTextReader(res);
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(xReader);
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("autosave")
         select new Configuration()
         {
             SaveOnoff = Convert.ToBoolean(c.Attribute("onoff").Value),
             Minute = c.Attribute("minute").Value,
          };
Config.SaveOnoff = filteredData.First().SaveOnoff;
Config.Minute = filteredData.First().Minute;
```

But I can't figure out how to read `<db> tag` values to my `Db Class` and add it to my `Configuration Class` instance. This is what I've done so far:

```
filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("db")
    select new Configuration()
    {
        DbList = new List<Db>
        {
            new Db
            {
                Dbid = Convert.ToInt32(c.Attribute("dbid").Value),
                Conn = c.Attribute("conn").Value,
                Writer = c.Attribute("writer").Value,
                Active = Convert.ToBoolean(c.Attribute("active").Value)
            }
        }
    };
foreach (Configuration conf in filteredData)
    {
        //Db newDb = new Db { Dbid = Convert.ToInt32(conf.Value) };
    Config.DbList.Add(conf.DbList[0]);
        //Config.DbList.Add(new Db{Active=conf.Active,Conn = conf.Conn,Dbid = conf.Dbid,DbOnoff = conf.DbOnoff,Englishname = conf.Englishname,Persianname = conf.Persianname,Writer = conf.Writer});
    }
```

`foreach` loops on time and the next loops throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error at `select new Configuration()`

Does anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: @Thirisangu - I you use `(string)` you don't need the `.Value`, and if use the `.Value` it will still throw Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.  Simply use `(string)c.Attribute("conn")` and `(string)c.Attribute("writer")`

Comment: @Tim Thank you. You saved the day. It's working fine now.

Comment: @AlexJolig - You're welcome.  I almost always use `(string)` when working in LINQ to XML, as it saves a lot of headaches.